# Multiple clients on a single Xvfb server/process?

Tags: xvfb

Is is possible to use only one Xvfb process to serve multiple clients simultaneously?

Or, phrasing it differently: A Xvfb process maps directly to one screen, i.e., multiple clients share the same screen, or each new client gets a new, isolated, screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple clients per Xfvb screen, much as your X display can have multiple clients.

Remember that Xvfb is essentially an XServer without a screen, just peeling off the actual video card writing and manipulation.

I'm curious as to why you need this? We needed to run this for Java code that couldn't run headless. It needed a frame buffer to write to even though it was dumping to a file only.

Comment: Thanks, Rich! I'm building a service that takes screenshots from webpages using QtWebkit. For that, I'll have multiple workers watching a queue and I was wondering if I'd have to have one Xvfb process for each of those workers or if I could use only one Xvfb process for all workers.

Comment: @Tiago Cool, I think you can do this with a single instance.  Good luck

Comment: @Tiago like http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/?