# 1 xvfb, multiple applications

Tags: xvfb

According to a previous question, [Multiple clients on a single Xvfb server/process?](https://superuser.com/questions/293793/multiple-clients-on-a-single-xvfb-server-process), I can run multiple clients on a single xvfb process. If this is true, then how can this be done?

Example:

xvfb app1

xvfb app2

app2 needs to take a screenshot of app1, but since app2 is in a different xvfb, it doesn't capture app1's xvfb screen. I need to be able to start both app1 and app2 using the same xvfb so the screen capture works. Note that app1 and app2 will be started at completely different points in the script (ie., I can't do 'xvfb app1 app2').

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get any solution?